# VB checking if object exists before creating

Tags: vb.net, vba

Is their a way to check an application exists before I write in the code to create the object

I know this is install and I can use it but what if I want the program to check first ?

```
Set objOutlook = GetObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you should verify if there is entry in Registry.
You can proceed as follows;

```
 Dim regKey As RegistryKey  

 regKey = My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Outlook.Application", False).OpenSubKey("CurVer", False)  

 If not string.IsNullOrEmpty(regKey.GetValue("")) then

// Your code

 End if
```